# What's the point of this line in the "Grabbing touch events" section. (Kivy)

Tags: kivy

I'm confused about touch.grab

[Documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/inputs.html#grabbing-touch-events) says

> The touch coordinate is not translated to your widget space because the touch is coming directly from the Window. It’s your job to convert the coordinate to your local space.

but when I ran the code below

```py3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.factory import Factory


class DragRecognizer(Factory.Widget):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            touch.grab(self)
            print('on_drag_begin', touch.pos)
            return True
        else:
            return super().on_touch_down(touch)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if touch.grab_current is self:
            touch.ungrab(self)
            print('on_drag_end', touch.pos, '(grab)')
            return True
        else:
            print('on_drag_end', touch.pos)
            return super().on_touch_up(touch)


root = Builder.load_string(r'''
<Widget>:
    canvas.after:
        Line:
            rectangle: self.x+2,self.y+2,self.width-3,self.height-3
            dash_offset: 5
            dash_length: 3

BoxLayout:
    Widget:
    RelativeLayout
        DragRecognizer:
            size_hint: 0.8, 0.8
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5, }
''')

runTouchApp(root)
```

and pressed mouse button.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxQ1p.png)

I expected like this

```
on_drag_begin (88, 111)
on_drag_end (88, 111)
on_drag_end (488, 111) (grab)
```

but what I got is

```
on_drag_begin (88, 111)
on_drag_end (88, 111)
on_drag_end (88, 111) (grab)
```

Grabbed touch is not Window coordinates! So I don't understand what's the point of the documentation. Sorry for my bad English. I really appreciate if you help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/kivy/kivy/pull/5925
The documentation was wrong. Sorry for replying too late.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the coordinate to your local space by using *instance.to_window(*instance.pos)*. Please refer to the example for details.

## snippet

```
to_window = instance.to_window(*instance.pos)
```

## Example

### main.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.properties import ListProperty


class DragRecognizer(Factory.Widget):
    pressed = ListProperty([0, 0])

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            touch.grab(self)
            self.pressed = touch.pos
            print('on_touch_down: on_drag_begin', touch.pos)
            return True

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if touch.grab_current is self:
            touch.ungrab(self)
            print('on_touch_up: on_drag_end', touch.pos, '(grab)')
            return True

    def on_pressed(self, instance, pos):
        print("Pressed at {}".format(pos))
        to_window = instance.to_window(*instance.pos)
        print("to_window = {}".format(to_window))
        to_widget = instance.to_widget(*to_window)
        print("to_widget = {}".format(to_widget))


root = Builder.load_string(r'''
<Widget>:
    canvas.after:
        Line:
            rectangle: self.x+2,self.y+2,self.width-3,self.height-3
            dash_offset: 5
            dash_length: 3

BoxLayout:
    Widget:
    RelativeLayout
        DragRecognizer:
            size_hint: 0.8, 0.8
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5, }
''')

runTouchApp(root)
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank for the reply (^_^).  So basically when on_touch_down() is called and touch.grab_current is self, touch.pos is not window coordinates, right? The coordinates is same as the non-grabbed touch. I thought the documentation was saying like "When you grab a touch, the coordinates is not translated to your widget space but window coordinates, so you have to convert it manually".  But practically touch.pos is not window coordinates so I still don't understand what's meaning of the documentation.

Comment: I mean I don't know why the documentation saying that. The coordinates of a grabbed-touch is same as non-grabbed-touch. (both outputs same pos (88, 111) )